# CN1 Socket cannot send >7200 bytes

Tags: codenameone

Having trouble sending a large number of bytes from CN1 client to Server. Code below works for anything less than ~7200 bytes. However at byte 7240 the bytes received by the server becomes all zeroes. Not sure why this is occurring, as the connection is still live. The server can still push bytes back just unsure why the client cannot send more data than ~7200. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
if (!outgoingMessages.isEmpty()) {
            Socket.connect("my.server.net", 1234, new SocketConnection() {
                @Override
                public void connectionEstablished(InputStream inStream, OutputStream outStream) {
                    try {
                            byte[] msgBytes = outgoingMessages.pop();
                            outStream.write(ByteConvertor.intToBytes(msgBytes.length));
                            outStream.write(msgBytes);
                    } catch(Exception err) {
                        err.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void connectionError(int errorCode, String message) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            });
        }
```

Clarification: This is specific to com.codename1.io.Socket and not Steve's CN1Sockets lib

Answer (score 1):

I think this might have been fixed by this [pull request](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/pull/1621), its not available in the simulator builds yet but should work in the source/device. We should update the plugin this week at some point so code should hopefully "just work".

Comment: Thanks Shai, I'll keep an eye out for the update! :)

Comment: Shai, after further testing, the issue is present on Android devices as well. Is this possibly a new issue and should I file a bug report?

Comment: Do you have a test case we can use to reproduce this? If so please file an issue: http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/